# Using clang++ with C++23 and gcc candiate 12 cannot find expected header

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, header-files, c++23

I'm wanting to use C++23's `<expected>`, but clang is unable to find it on my system unless I add `-stdlib=libc++`, which causes other errors with various shared libs compiled against `libstdc++`.

I have gcc-12 installed, `<expected>` exists in `/usr/include/c++/12`.

clang seems be using gcc-12 as the candidate:

```
$ clang++-17 -v
Ubuntu clang version 17.0.6 (++20231208085857+6009708b4367-1~exp1~20231208085958.76)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

If it is using `gcc-12` as the candidate, why are the headers in `/usr/include/c++/12` not being picked up?

Comment: C++23 support in the major compilers is still evolving. It is expected (pun intended) that these kinds of issues will occur, especially when using one C++ compiler with a differerent C++ compiler's header files.

Comment: I mean sure, but that's on clang. They are the ones who default to using GNU's libstdc++.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not finding the header, rather than finding the header but not compiling the contents?

Do you get and error like:

`test.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'expected' file not found`

or do you get an error like:

`test.cc:10:6: error: no template named 'expected' in namespace 'std'`

?

The GCC 12 implementation of `std::expected` is gated on the following feature test macro:

```cpp
#if __cplusplus > 202002L && __cpp_concepts >= 202002L
```

Clang 17 with `-std=c++2b` defines:

```cpp
#define __cplusplus 202101L
#define __cpp_concepts 201907L
```

This means that when it compiles the `<expected>` header it will just treat it as a completely empty header, and not define `std::expected`.

The reason that GCC requires `__cpp_concepts >= 202002L` is because it depends on [P0848R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0848r3.html) "Conditionally Trivial Special Member Functions" which Clang apparently doesn't support.